# Javascript Ajax response type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm doing the 70-480 exam, and one of the prep questions was to find the alert output.
My guess would be that alert would show "type: undefined". But the supposed correct answer says it shows "type: int".

I'm struggling to understand where I'm failing here.
The four points confusing me are:

- Posting will execute the function in the WebService, however,
- How is it that the success function response gets a document object? Is this a standard success response for a POST?
- Doesn't success return true? Or... Is it returning a truthy http code? But then again, how can that relate to a documentElement.localName?
- Upon a search on Google, I found that localName gives me the name of the node. I haven't seen indication it gives me the type of the object retrieved.

**Code below:**

[in WebService.asmx]

```
private int myNumber = 57;
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public int GetNumber() {
    int diff = new Random().Next(32);
    myNumber = myNumber + diff - 16;
    return myNumber;
}
```

[in JavaScript]

```
function getNumber() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/WebService.asmx/GetNumber",
        success: function (response) {
        alert("type: " + response.documentElement.localName);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: [`documentElement.localName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/localName) is always a string. However, you're not looking for the `type` of `localName`, but for it's contents.

Answer (score 1):

Your web service calls `return myNumber;` which is an `int`

When you call your ajax, and it completes successfully, the function you provide in `success` is called. This function is automatically passed the response from the web service.

In your success function you call `response.documentElement.localName` which gives you `int` because the only thing in your response is a single integer

See  [.documentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) and [.localName](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-NodeNSLocalN)

Comment: Was a relatively good answer. But still questions buzzing. What is the response of the success made of? According to the WebService, it should be a JSON, but seems to be receiving an XML, hence the code hints at a node such as the root element of the data sent back. I'd imagine the data in response would be similar to <int>20</int> so it could get the localName of the data posted to the service.

Comment: @RafaelVentura All depends on your server/service. The response can be JSON, XML, Text, or any other format that can be represented by a string. Your server appears to be responding with xml in this case.

Comment: *"which gives you int because the only thing in your response is a single integer"* What exactly is an integer in javascript? A string representation of a asp.net integer can be converted to a Number, but it would available as a string first unless already parsed from a json string or xml to a js object or array.

Comment: As @KevinB points out, you appear to be returning xml. While you seem to want to return json, you don't actually build any json, you just return the Int directly

Comment: That's the answer that explains it best. I would need to build a JSON and return it. Many thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's ajax() function you can specify what format you expect back from server. You can set that expectation using the dataType keyword. Default is intelligent guess, so it tries to make xml, json, script or html out of the response. If none can be guessed, you get a string.

For getting the http return code, use the statusCode keyword, which should be a JSON with HTTP codes as keys and functions as values. Example:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    }
  }
});
```

As for the success field, the docs are pretty specific about it:

> **success**
>
> Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
> passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
> according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback
> function (...)

Consider reading the whole documentation of jQuery's ajax function at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/